# Selecting DocumentID when importing data from google sheets API to Firestore

Tags: firebase, api, google-cloud-firestore, google-sheets-api

I want to send data from google sheets API to Firestore. I have achieved this goal but I would like to select my own **documentID** and not have a generated one.

I want to send data to specific **userID** so I plan on inputting the data on the google sheets spreadsheets and having that data stored under that **userID** in Firestore.

In my spreadsheet I have a field titled **userID**. Is there a way to modify my script code so I can use the **userID** as the **documentID**?

[image: image1]

Script code can be seen here:

![image2][2]

```
var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore (email, key, projectId);  
  // get document data from ther spreadsheet
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheetname = "Sheet1";
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname); 


   // get the last row and column in order to define range
   var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow(); // get the last row
   var sheetLC = sheet.getLastColumn(); // get the last column

   var dataSR = 2; // the first row of data
   // define the data range
   var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheetLR-dataSR+1,sheetLC);


   // get the data
   var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
   // get the number of length of the object in order to establish a       loop value
   var sourceLen = sourceData.length;

  // Loop through the rows
   for (var i=0;i<sourceLen;i++){
     if(sourceData[i][1] !== '') {
       var data = {};
       data.userid = sourceData[i][0];
       data.store = sourceData[i][1];
       data.price = sourceData[i][2];
       data.department = sourceData[i][3];
       data.date = sourceData[i][4];
   
  
       var userId = sourceData[i][0]
       firestore.createDocument("User/" + userId + "/Receipts", data);
  
   

     }

  }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome on Stack Overflow. Please include your code as text in your question, in order for us to copy it and adapt it. Thanks.

Comment: Please do edit the question and copy the text of the code into the question itself instead of showing an image.  Images with text can be difficult to read, copy, and search, and are not accessible to those using screen readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make the assumption that you use the
[FirestoreGoogleAppsScript](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript) library, since you do `firestore.createDocument()`.

As explained in the library documentation, you can specify the ID of the new Firestore document by passing the entire path of the document (i.e. collection + ID separated by a slash) as follows:

```
// ...
var userId = sourceData[i][0]
firestore.createDocument("User/" + userId, data);
```

Comment: That works! Thank you. However it only takes one line from the spreadsheet and if I have a second line with new data for the same userid it doesn't show up in firestore. Is there a way I can send more that one line of data from the spreadsheet to Firestore under the same UserID?

Comment: You can only have one document with a specific ID in a specific collection. You could maybe use a subcollection, e.g. `firestore.createDocument("User/" + userId + "/documents", data);`.